# Using GETPIVOTDATA with date range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot, pivot-table

How can I use GETPIVOTDATA to work with a date range?

`=GETPIVOTDATA("QTY",$A$1, "Date","1/1/2000 ~ 1/1/2019")` or
1/1/2000 ~ Today() or group all past dates from today (date < Today())

Something like this.

I get a REF error if I group the dates directly in the pivot table...

Comment: I also tried =GETPIVOTDATA("QTY",$A$1, "Date",DATE(2000,1,1)<=TODAY())

Which doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an Example, hope which will help you to get an idea.

Else please elaborate your question with examples "snaps/excel file", which will help to give you answer easily.

[image]

**Formula:**

**{=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Volume",$E$17,"Date",ROW(INDIRECT(H30&":"&H31))),0))}**

Formula Array:
Produce enclosing { } by entering
formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER!

Comment: This make sense. If I have dates in columns instead of rows do I simple change the formula to COLUMN(INDIRECT(A1&":"&H1))?  And can't I not use Date < Today() or define a month instead?